# Manually selecting Salesforce for Outlook contacts

Tags: salesforce-for-outlook

Is it possible to manually select which contacts get synced to your outlook via salesforce for outlook. Via a clean or a hack way, doesn't matter.

Basically each user should be able to select which contacts he wants in his outlook. However, there can't be any changes to the owner, that must stay the same!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you set up a Salesforce for Outlook configuration, you need to identify a [data set](https://help.salesforce.com/htviewhelpdoc?id=outlookcrm_config_contact_filters.htm&siteLang=en_US) for contacts to sync. One of the options is to sync contacts that the user follows in Chatter. You could set up the data set so the only option selected is the Chatter one and then train your users to follow contacts they want to sync.

Comment: This might be a winner! I'll check it out, thanks!

Comment: This works! And is by far the easiest and nicest way of fixing this problem!

Comment: Does unfollow record delete it from Outlook if I set salesforce always wins? It doesn't do that for me.

Comment: I suspect it will leave it in Outlook, but not update it anymore. https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=outlookcrm_sync.htm

Answer (score 1):

In a way, you can.

When you set up the Outlook plugin you are given the choice to pick  which Contacts folder to sync. You could instruct your users to create a separate Contacts folder in Outlook (e.g. "Professional Contacts") point the tool to that folder and have them move the contacts they want synchronized to that folder.

Comment: what if they sync both ways? won't all the salesforce contacts be pushed in that folder then?

Comment: Yes, all the Contacts in that user's data set would end up in that Outlook folder. You set up rules for what data set users would bring down, e.g. Only those they own, those on accounts they own etc. Most of it is centered around ownership somehow.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't work with owners, there can be multiple users selecting the same contact for manual download, but because they are working with a huge list of contacts 50k+ in salesforce, these can't all end up in their outlook (because of a sync with their mobile phones)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can accomplish this with Salesforce for Outlook.  You will need to use a paid application like [Riva](http://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N30000001srGuEAI) that allows for more customization.  I worked with them to fulfill this exact requirement.